# in scala why does for yield return option instead of string

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala I'm trying to understand for/yield and don't understand why the following code returns an option not a String

```
val opString: Option[String] = Option("test")
val optionStr : Option[String] = for {
  op <- opString
} yield {
  opString match {
    case Some(s) => s
    case _ => "error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A for-expression is syntactic sugar for a series of `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter` calls. Your specific for-expression is translated to something like this:

```
opString.map(op => opString match {
    case Some(s) => s
    case _ => "error"
})
```

As you can see, your expression will just map over `opString` and not unwrap it in any way.

Comment: In fact, your expression is equivalent to `opString` itself ;) If the `Option` is empty, then the function passed to the `map` function will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Desugared expression for your for ... yield expression is:

```
val optionStr = opString.map {
  op => 
     opString match { 
       case Some(s) => s
       case _ => "error"
     }
}
```

The type of opString match {...} is String, so the result type of applying map (String => String) to Option[String] is Option[String]

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `getOrElse`:

```
opString.getOrElse("error")
```

This is equivalent to:

```
opString match {
  case Some(s) => s
  case _ => "error"
}
```